# Macro no funciona desde botón

Tags: excel, vba, macros

He creado una macro que importa datos de un archivo CSV, luego otra que los extrae y los pega en otra hoja y una tercera que ejecuta las dos macros anteriores seguidas

Cuando las ejecuto desde el editor de VBA o desde excel en la pestaña "Macros" funcionan perfectamente (solo funcionan si estoy en la hoja "BASE DATOS_POSTES", pero bueno eso es lo de menos)

El problema es que si asigno un botón a la macro de extraer o a la conjunta da error (los botones están en la hoja "BASE DATOS_POSTES").

- A veces solo copia la primera columna
- Otras veces da error 1004 definido por la aplicacion o el objeto en esta linea :

  ```
  Set RngOrigen = Worksheets("BASE DATOS_CARGAS").Range(Cells(i, "AA"), 
  Cells(FFinCaso, "AA"))
  ```

¿Sabeis de qué puede ser este problema de que la macro no funcione desde el botón pero si desde los otros sitios?

```vb
Sub extraccion_datos()

Dim UltiFila As Integer
Dim Caso, Extraccion As String
Dim FFinCaso As Integer
Dim ColPegado As Integer
Dim CasoCompara As String
Dim RngOrigen As Excel.Range
Dim RngPegado As Excel.Range



'Activación de los rangos
Set RngOrigen = Worksheets("BASE DATOS_CARGAS").Range("AA1")
Set RngPegado = Worksheets("FORMULAS").Range("A2")

UltiFila = Worksheets("BASE DATOS_CARGAS").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
'Celda que contiene el valor 1000 para pasar los N a kN y los Nmm a Nm
Worksheets("BASE DATOS_CARGAS").Range("V15").Copy
'Pegado especial que divide toda la columna AB por 1000
Worksheets("BASE DATOS_CARGAS").Range("AB1:AB" & UltiFila).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlDivide, SkipBlanks:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

For i = 1 To UltiFila
    Extraccion = Mid(Cells(i, "AB"), 2, 7)
        If Extraccion = "Loadset" Then
            Caso = Mid(Cells(i, "AB"), 10)
            FFinCaso = Worksheets("BASE DATOS_CARGAS").Cells(i, "AB").End(xlDown).Row
            For j = 1 To 30 Step 3
                CasoCompara = Worksheets("FORMULAS").Cells(1, j)
                If CasoCompara = Caso Then
                    ColPegado = j
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            Set RngOrigen = Worksheets("BASE DATOS_CARGAS").Range(Cells(i, "AA"), Cells(FFinCaso, "AA"))
            RngOrigen.Copy
            Set RngPegado = Worksheets("FORMULAS").Cells(2, ColPegado)
            RngPegado.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Set RngOrigen = Worksheets("BASE DATOS_CARGAS").Range(Cells(i, "AB"), Cells(FFinCaso, "AB"))
            RngOrigen.Copy
            Set RngPegado = Worksheets("FORMULAS").Cells(2, ColPegado + 2)
            RngPegado.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False


    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu código debes verificar las lineas que hacen referencia a "cells", por ejemplo esta:

```
Extraccion = Mid(Cells(i, "AB"), 2, 7)
```

Ahi Debes indicar a que hoja le haces referencia, ya que solo pones "cells", podria ser de esta manera

```
Extraccion = Mid(Worksheets("BASE DATOS_CARGAS").Cells(i, "AB"), 2, 7)
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Prueba poniendo esta línea. Los direccionamientos con Range y Cells mezclados tienen ciertos matices.

```
Set RngOrigen = Worksheets("BASE DATOS_CARGAS").Range(Cells(i, "AA").Address, Cells(FFinCaso, "AA").Address)
```